# Pressing editButtonItem does not enable/disable deletion swiping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[Using this tutorial](http://www.ryanwright.me/cookbook/ios/objc/uitableview/add-table-row), I have been able to override my table editing to allow the press of a editButtonItem to toggle an "Add Row" button. However, I also want it to not allow swipe delete unless editing is turned on--yet swipe delete is always enabled.

I've looked into other Stack Overflow questions with the same issue, but it seems like I have implemented everything that other users suggest needs to be implemented. I must be missing something.

Following is my table editing code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableData = ptrBookmarks;

    numberOfSections = 1; // for editing: initial number of sections

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    //allow row selection during editing.
    //if the "Add Row" row is selected we can trigger an insert.
    //rather than forcing the using to click the (+) icon directly
    self.aTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if ([self isEditing]) // the current view is in editing mode, return count + an extra row
        return [tableData count] + 1;
    else // return count
        return [tableData count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    //if number of rows is greater than the total number of rows in the data set
    //and this view is in editing mode.
    //Initialize the cell for "Add Row"
    //there will be an extra row once SetEditing: is called
    if(indexPath.row >= ptrBookmarks1.count && [self isEditing]){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Add Row";
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}


//VIEW CONTROLLER METHOD: IMPORTANT
//this is a method of the view controller
//if we use apple's editing button as follows:
//self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
//then this method will be called automatically for us.
//if we are using a button callback or similar method,
//then we need to call setEditing: manually on the view
-(void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{

    //wrap our code in an if statement
    //only run the code if we are not swipe deleting a row.
    //if we were called due to a swipeDelete action, ignore it
    if(isSwipeDeleting == NO){
        //call parent
        [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];


        //if editing mode
        if(editing){
            //batch the table view changes so that everything happens at once
            [self.aTableView beginUpdates];
            //for each section, insert a row at the end of the table
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++){
                //create an index path for the new row
                NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tableData.count inSection:i];
                //insert the NSIndexPath to create a new row. NOTE: this method takes an array of paths
                [self.aTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            //animate the changes now
            [self.aTableView endUpdates];
        }else{
            //batch the table view changes so that everything happens at once
            [self.aTableView beginUpdates];
            //for each section, insert a row at the end of the table
            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++){
                //create an index path for the new row
                NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:tableData.count inSection:i];
                //insert the NSIndexPath to create a new row. NOTE: this method takes an array of paths
                [self.aTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            //animate the changes now
            [self.aTableView endUpdates];
        }
    }
}


//DELEGATE METHOD:
//this method will be called for every row and allows us to set the
//editing syle icon(Delete,Insert)
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // Detemine if it's in editing mode
    //if (self.aTableView.editing) {
    //use the + icon(add icon) on row
    //if this is the additional row created in setEditing:animated:
    if(indexPath.row >= tableData.count){
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    }
    else{
        //use the delete icon on this row
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
    //}
    //else
    //return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

//handle the deletion insertion
//this method is called when the delete or insert icon has been press.
//we should update our dataSource by inserting or removing the selected INDEX
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //remove row from datasource
        [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //remove the row in the tableView because the deleteIcon was clicked
        [self.aTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        //add a new row to the datasource
        [tableData addObject:@"New Icon"];
        //insert a row in the tableView because the plusIcon was clicked.
        [self.aTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                               withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}


//if we are in editing mode we do not want to perform Seque Transition
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"MyDetailView"] && [self isEditing]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}


//this method is called when the user swipes to delete a row.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    isSwipeDeleting = YES;//user just swipe to delete a row
}
//when the user cancel the swipe or click the delete button
//this method is call
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    isSwipeDeleting = NO;//swipe to delete ended. No longer showing the DELETE button in cell
}



// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {

    NSString *item;

    item = [[tableData objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [tableData insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

    [item release];
}




// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

//DELEGATE METHOD:
//the user selected a row
//In order for the user to perform an INSERTION action on a row,
//they have to click the + icon icon. We can implement this method
//so that they can click anywhere on the add row to add a new row
//tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES; must be set
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //deselect the selected row with animatiion
    [self.aTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //if the selected  row was the "Add Row" row call tableView:commitEditingStyle:
    //to add a new row
    if (indexPath.row >= tableData.count && [self isEditing]) {
        [self tableView:tableView commitEditingStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else { // otherwise do regular table item selection
        [self.delegate didTapBookmarksTable:[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. I changed the main if statement in the `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` method to say `self.editing` instead of `self.aTableView.editing`:

```
// Detemine if it's in editing mode
    if (self.editing) {
        //use the + icon(add icon) on row
        //if this is the additional row created in setEditing:animated:
        if(indexPath.row >= tableData.count){
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
        }
        else {
            //use the delete icon on this row
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
        }
    }
    else
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
```